# Kotlin: confusion with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin

Realm returns a list of `FooRealm`.
`FooRealm` is a `Foo`

```
public class FooRealm extends RealmObject implements Foo
```

But I get a type mismatch:

```
Type mismatch:
Required: Observable<List<FooRealm>>
Found: Observable<List<Foo>>
```

when I do:

```
override fun getFoo(): Observable<List<Foo>> {
    return Realm.getDefaultInstance().use { realm ->
        realm.where(FooRealm::class.java)
                .equalTo("bar", true)
                .findAllAsync()
                .asObservable()                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the original `fun getFoo(): ...` signature. Is it in the interface or in the base class? Is the type of `Observable<List<Foo>>` a generic in the base class or fixed?

Comment: Hi `interface FooRepo {
    fun getFoo(): Observable<List<Foo>>
 }`

Comment: What is `Realm`? Is this your class or from a library?

Comment: Realm is a database, a library

Comment: Are you sure both `Observable`s are the same type?

Comment: Why you are retruning Observable<List<Foo>>. Observable<List<FooRealm>> is the right way

Comment: Where do you actually get this error at? Is it having issues compiling the code you have there? Is it failing when using `getFoo()`? There might be different cases where type inference might fail or help you.